# Sign apk file with p12 certificate file corrupted

Tags: android, ssl, cryptography, apk, recovery

I have a big problem in the moment when I try distribute an apk file in OS X, I think, something is broke. The txt file with the passphrase of my p12 certificate are corrupted and I don't have the passphrase, the file have this string:

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAk5iPIR0NOw0QNJrdXSvZngt7SLOWHszXqjEK0I2cOO+I+LWtOi9NiLHYRSFISznCBtccNp1prFuLYiVZOpegxgZyx8i7GXUWj9047MtKW5rnOVNHBzD4CcHGW8DDWU4fCfLQyYj/OFxivzTbi3vnUZkX/Ma/iZj8tMazFtu5yfn+b0hQTfZCZPWWSaJwyNYA17ZHZZIQh2mNLWjg0h3ZGm/yVj0BuBwZw3QyBfCd61mwhXGFpjmFFQHIZGgeCHZQYDewMwiNkx16y/auJCNmoGxDTwOn8KDn7LuWRRnUSa0YMTb0tVodzFmpLTGtjQ9yDeyiLZLKGIH11itn9SHxawIRKDS
```

1 This is other kind of certificate?

2- If not, I can recover my app?

This this is my first post, regards.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "corrupted"?

Comment: In the passphrase of the other p12 apps i have "TestPhrase" "OtherWord1234"... in this case have this string